# Средства выражения категории рода

Tags: морфология

Скажите, пожалуйста, у обоих слов "бык-корова" будет лексическое средство выражения категории рода?
Всегда ли присутствует  морфологическое средство выражения категории рода или в таком случае, который приведён выше, оно будет отсутствовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Всегда ли присутствует морфологическое средство выражения категории рода или
 в таком случае, который приведён выше, оно будет отсутствовать?
```

Речь идёт о том, что в **данных** словах для определения рода **достаточно только лексического** средства выражения, ведь названия лиц и животных имеют семантику пола:
"**бык – "самец** коровы и некоторых других пород рогатого скота" – **корова – "домашнее молочное животное, самка крупного рогатого скота**, а также некоторых других рогатых животных, например лося, оленя".

Род имен существительных имеет реальную семантику только в тех случаях, когда им характеризуются названия лиц и животных: названия лиц мужского пола относятся к мужскому роду (брат, бык), названия лиц женского пола – к женскому роду (сестра, девочка, львица).

Но семантические различия категории рода одушевленных имен существительных в современном русском языке проявляются непоследовательно. Выявляются отклонения (колебания) в роде:

•   1) отсутствуют указания на половые различия у названий многих животных (зоонимах), особенно тех, которые не имеют хозяйственного назначения (кит, акула);

•   2) возможно употребление слов мужского рода (типа врач, хирург, профессор, доцент, товарищ) для обозначения лиц женского пола. Согласование здесь возможно по смыслу (наш врач и наша врач; лекцию читал профессор и лекцию читала профессор), но нормой является грамматическое согласование по мужскому роду,

•   3) для называния лиц употребляются слова общего рода (типа директор, председатель, староста, неряха, забияка и т.п.).

Но здесь имеются и другие средства выражения, например, морфологигическое: нулевое окончание, 2 склонение, твёрдая основа - муж.род, 1 скл.. окончание -а,-я- жен. род. Однако  только по этому признаку род нельзя определить, папа, дядя - тоже 1 склонение, но род мужской.

Есть и синтаксическое средство. Род определяется по согласуемому с существительным определению или по глаголу прошедшего времени: бежал огромный бык, шла пятнистая корова.

Так что и морфологическое, и синтаксическое средства присутствуют, но играют второстепенную, не главную роль, главную в данном случае играет лексическое средство - семантика. Зная семантику, мы подбираем определение и сказуемое.